# mongodb can't start on windows?

Tags: mongodb

when i tried to start mongodb using the command "mongod.exe" on the command line, it throws the following error..

```
C:\mongodb-win32-x86_64-2.0.6\bin>mongod.exe
mongod.exe --help for help and startup options
Thu Aug 09 11:56:48 [initandlisten] MongoDB starting : pid=6892 port=27017 dbpat
h=/data/db 64-bit host=user4-PC
Thu Aug 09 11:56:48 [initandlisten] db version v2.0.6, pdfile version 4.5
Thu Aug 09 11:56:48 [initandlisten] git version: e1c0cbc25863f6356aa4e31375add7b
b49fb05bc
Thu Aug 09 11:56:48 [initandlisten] build info: windows sys.getwindowsversion(ma
jor=6, minor=1, build=7601, platform=2, service_pack='Service Pack 1') BOOST_LIB
_VERSION=1_42
Thu Aug 09 11:56:48 [initandlisten] options: {}
**************
old lock file: \data\db\mongod.lock.  probably means unclean shutdown,
but there are no journal files to recover.
this is likely human error or filesystem corruption.
found 3 dbs.
see: http://dochub.mongodb.org/core/repair for more information
*************
Thu Aug 09 11:56:48 [initandlisten] exception in initAndListen: 12596 old lock f
ile, terminating
Thu Aug 09 11:56:48 dbexit:
Thu Aug 09 11:56:48 [initandlisten] shutdown: going to close listening sockets..
.
Thu Aug 09 11:56:48 [initandlisten] shutdown: going to flush diaglog...
Thu Aug 09 11:56:48 [initandlisten] shutdown: going to close sockets...
Thu Aug 09 11:56:48 [initandlisten] shutdown: waiting for fs preallocator...
Thu Aug 09 11:56:48 [initandlisten] shutdown: lock for final commit...
Thu Aug 09 11:56:48 [initandlisten] shutdown: final commit...
Thu Aug 09 11:56:48 [initandlisten] shutdown: closing all files...
Thu Aug 09 11:56:48 [initandlisten] closeAllFiles() finished
Thu Aug 09 11:56:48 dbexit: really exiting now
```

i really cant start mongodb.. Help me to start mongodb as windows service and rectify the error. I already read the installation guide and followed the same but still throwing the error.

Comment: remove \data\db\mongod.lock file and try again.

Comment: still not working.. it hung up with this..
Thu Aug 09 12:11:43 [clientcursormon] mem (MB) res:20 virt:79 mapped:0

Comment: An adequate solution can be found at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13700261/mongodb-wont-start-after-server-crash

Answer (score 42, accepted):

Delete the lock file `\data\db\mongod.lock`, and run `mongod --repair`.

[source](http://www.mkyong.com/mongodb/old-lock-file-datadbmongod-lock-probably-means-unclean-shutdown/)

Comment: where is the file on windows ?

Comment: On Windows I just needed to run mongod --repair

Comment: Be warned that doing this on a large database will take potentially many hours and requires enough disk space for another copy of the entire database. You also shouldn't need it if you are using journalling. http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/recover-data-following-unexpected-shutdown/

Answer (score 2):

You definitely want to run repair if you remove the lock file. If you do run mongodb with journaling you should not have to repair. More info on both can be found at http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Durability+and+Repair

Answer (score 1):

**Bugfix**
If it don´t help to delete the *mongodb.lock* file, try to repair MongoDB with the command *--repair*

**Start MongoDB as a Service**
If you want to start MongoDB as a Service you can addthe command *--service*. if you have multiple instances, cou can use also *--serviceName{name}* and *--serviceDisplayName{name}* for uniqe names. You can find [here](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Windows+Service) more information about starting as a Service