# Mongo Shell couldn't connect to the local server

Tags: mongodb

I'm starting MongoDB using the following command:

```
sumeet@sumeet-acer:~$ sudo service mongod start
```

I get a reply as:

```
mongod start/running, process 7209
sumeet@sumeet-acer:~$
```

But when I try to enter MongoDB shell by typing `mongo` I get the following error:

```
sumeet@sumeet-acer:~$ mongo
MongoDB shell version: 2.0.4
connecting to: test
Fri Jun 12 14:01:59 Error: couldn't connect to server 127.0.0.1 shell/mongo.js:84
exception: connect failed
```

Answer (score 0):

[By default, `mongod` and `mongos` use the 27017 port](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/default-mongodb-port/). Without any option, the client will try to connect to a server running on *localhost* and listening at that port.

A few general advices here:

1. check if the `mongod` server is really running (`ps -edf | grep mongod`);
2. check if it uses the default port (look in the config file<sup>1</sup>, or use `nmap localhost -p0-65535` or `netstat | grep 27017`);
3. if `mongod` is not running, check in the log<sup>2</sup> for clues about what goes wrong.

---

<sub><sup>1</sup> `/etc/mongodb.conf` (on Debian-like systems at least)</sub>
<sub><sup>2</sup> `/var/log/mongodb` (on Debian-like systems at least)</sub>

Answer (score 0):

The default IP and Port for MongoDB is 127.0.0.1 & 27017.

If you are using config file for specifying settings than re-verify IP & Port mentioned in it.

If you are going with default option than mongod should function as expected.

try mongo 127.0.0.1:27017

Answer (score 0):

this worked for me
For MongoDB 2.2.2 running on Ubuntu 12.10, it's in /var/lib/mongodb/mongod.lock

and after that running the repair command

```
sudo -u mongodb mongod --repair --dbpath /var/lib/mongodb/
```

courtesy: https://stackoverflow.com/a/13700262/4907105