# Mongod unclean shutdown

Tags: mongodb, repair

new to this ..so my MONGOD unexpectedly shutdown and i can't seem to repair it ..this is what i see when i try to start up ./mongod

```
**2018-04-21T19:59:06.237+0000 ** WARNING: --rest is specified without --httpinterface,
2018-04-21T19:59:06.238+0000 **          enabling http interface
warning: bind_ip of 0.0.0.0 is unnecessary; listens on all ips by default
2018-04-21T19:59:06.241+0000 [initandlisten] MongoDB starting : pid=2848 port=27017 dbpath=data 64-bit host=omarr11-webdevbootcamp-5900192
2018-04-21T19:59:06.241+0000 [initandlisten] db version v2.6.12
2018-04-21T19:59:06.241+0000 [initandlisten] git version: d73c92b1c85703828b55c2916a5dd4ad46535f6a
2018-04-21T19:59:06.241+0000 [initandlisten] build info: Linux build5.ny.cbi.10gen.cc 2.6.32-431.3.1.el6.x86_64 #1 SMP Fri Jan 3 21:39:27 UTC 2014 x86_64 BOOST_LIB_VERSION=1_49
2018-04-21T19:59:06.241+0000 [initandlisten] allocator: tcmalloc
2018-04-21T19:59:06.241+0000 [initandlisten] options: { net: { bindIp: "0.0.0.0", http: { RESTInterfaceEnabled: true, enabled: true } }, storage: { dbPath: "data", journal: { enabled: false } } }
************** 
Unclean shutdown detected.
Please visit http://dochub.mongodb.org/core/repair for recovery instructions.
*************
2018-04-21T19:59:06.241+0000 [initandlisten] exception in initAndListen: 12596 old lock file, terminating
2018-04-21T19:59:06.241+0000 [initandlisten] dbexit: 
2018-04-21T19:59:06.241+0000 [initandlisten] shutdown: going to close listening sockets...
2018-04-21T19:59:06.241+0000 [initandlisten] shutdown: going to flush diaglog...
2018-04-21T19:59:06.241+0000 [initandlisten] shutdown: going to close sockets...
2018-04-21T19:59:06.241+0000 [initandlisten] shutdown: waiting for fs preallocator...
2018-04-21T19:59:06.242+0000 [initandlisten] shutdown: closing all files...
2018-04-21T19:59:06.242+0000 [initandlisten] closeAllFiles() finished
2018-04-21T19:59:06.242+0000 [initandlisten] dbexit: really exiting now**
```

can someone help me repair this please?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [MongoDB won't start after server crash](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13700261/mongodb-wont-start-after-server-crash)

Comment: Have you tried the suggested approach ("Please visit http://dochub.mongodb.org/core/repair for recovery instructions.")? It appears that you have disabled the journal, so your best recovery option (aside from restoring from a backup) is to run the database repair command as per the link in your log output. Make sure you take a backup of your data files before attempting any repair. I would strongly recommend leaving the journal enabled and upgrading to a supported version of MongoDB (2.6 reached end-of-life in Oct, 2016).

Comment: hi Stennie.. thanks for the reply.. yes i have tried that and i still have not been able to solve the problem.. im new to this so i actually don't know how i would enable journal.. can you guide me through to enable journal?

Comment: got it to work! ..it was the mongod.lock file that needed to be deleted ..its working fine now.. thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> You should look for the lock file (mongod.lock) in the data folder of
>   the mongodb and you need to delete it and try to start again.

In case you have some data corruption issue you can try repair option https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/recover-data-following-unexpected-shutdown/ . But in case it is just normal course of learning deleting the mongod.lock file should start the mongod process again...

Comment: Hey Devesh ..that's exactly what the problem was.. i cd into data ..found the "mongod.lock" file and deleted it ..it working now..  thanks